# Navigation component: how to list the fragments on the back stack?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

For debugging purposes I need to know which `Fragment`s (I need the class names like `MyCoolFragment`) are on the back stack and in which order they are on the back stack. How can I do that when using the [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)?

I hoped for something like this:

```
findNavController().backStack.forEach {
    // print it.toString()
}
```

but when I try to use this, Android Studio tells me

[image]

So, how can I watch what's on the back stack? I am currently working with `2.3.0-alpha04`, in case it matters.

Answer (score 3):

For debugging purposes, you can ignore the lint error and list non-NavGraph destinations on the back stack.

```kotlin
val breadcrumb = navController
    .currentBackStack
    .value
    .map {
        it.destination
    }
    .filterNot {
        it is NavGraph
    }
    .joinToString(" > ") {
        it.displayName.split('/')[1]
    }

// e.g. first_fragment > second_fragment > third_fragment
```

Comment: This seems incorrect, this only prints one step behind. For example, 1 -> 2 -> 3(current screen) then, it prints 1 > 2. but destination is 3.

Comment: My answer does not guarantee to print the current fragment, but to print fragments in the back stack. You can check if your expected fragment exists in `navController.currentBackStack`.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't available at runtime. It is only possible when using the [`TestNavHostController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/testing/TestNavHostController) class as part of the `navigation-testing` artifact as a way of verifying your back stack as part of a test.